# SQL - HAVING with recursive statement

Tags: sql, recursion, having

I am not sure the title corresponds to my problem but this is the best way I could describe it.

I was wondering if it was possible theoretically to have a query with a recursive statement in the having clause. For instance:

```
  SELECT a_name
  FROM (
    SELECT Author.id as a_id, Author.name as a_name, COUNT ( * ) as science_fiction_per_author
    FROM Title, Author, Title_tags, Tags, Publication_authors, Publication, Publication_content
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY a_id
    HAVING science_fiction_per_author = MAX(science_fiction_per_author)
  );
```

Comment: It isn't possible. You could replace `science_fiction_per_author` in the left side with `COUNT(*)`, but you cannot put it inside another aggregate function like `MAX(COUNT(*))`.

Comment: which DBMS are you using

Comment: Additionally, you should avoid using [old-style `JOIN` syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Except using the already mentioned JOIN syntax instead of the comma separated syntax, I would suggest to encapsulate the count query either in a cte or a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really recursion but you can use the same phrase twice to find the individual with the highest count. This is based on the movie database at http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations

The phrase

```
  SELECT actor.name,count(movieid) moviesPerActor
  FROM actor join casting ON actor.id=actorid
  GROUP BY actor.name
```

Lists each actor name and the number of movies made.

The same phrase is used twice. The A version is used to find the highest number of movies made by a single actor, the B version is used to identify that actor.

```
SELECT B.name from
(SELECT MAX(moviesPerActor) as highestNumberOfMovies
 FROM(
  SELECT actor.name,count(movieid) moviesPerActor
  FROM actor join casting ON actor.id=actorid
  GROUP BY actor.name
) as A) as A1
JOIN
(
  SELECT actor.name,count(movieid) moviesPerActor
  FROM actor join casting ON actor.id=actorid
  GROUP BY actor.name
) as B
ON B.moviesPerActor = highestNumberOfMovies
```

In some versions of SQL (including MSSQL and Oracle) you can use windowing functions to identify the element with the highest value more efficiently.